# How to assign a dynamic tag?

Tags: android, exception, tags, android-linearlayout

I have a `LinearLayout` that is dynamically declared through the Run_Time, though i don't have a fixed names or tags to define that Layout, though i tried to assign a tag to wach Layout depends on some variable and retrieve it by that variable later, like that :

```
layout.setTag(index , "something"); // "index" is a variable it's value obtained through the run_time
```

but i got that error :

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(643): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The key must be an application-specific resource id.
```

and after search i found that the problem is that i must assign a fixed resource to that tag but then i won't be able to differentiate between the different layout , so is there's a way to reach my approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're not able to use setTag(int, Object) is because android require a pre-compiled unique id in the 'int' argument.

one way is:

declare your tag in String file like follow:

```
<string name="FirstTag">1</string> 
<string name="SecondTag">2</string>
```

and for setting that use:

```
layout.setTag(R.string.FirstTag, "something");
```

and for getting value:

```
layout.getTag(R.string.FirstTag).toString();
```

**another way** is create a new file called values/tags.xml and write:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item name="FirstTag" type="id">1</item>
</resources>
```

**OR** you can use `R.id.*` as Tag Id too, i think you can handle your problem with that

Comment: May be worth pointing out that it doesn't have to be a `String`, but any resource ID

Comment: that's the something i wanna avoid as i mentioned i want it to be declared from a variable obtained through the run_time

Comment: android require a pre-compiled unique id , you can set layout.setTag("something"); if you have just one tag

Comment: see my Edit @MRefaat, i think that is best way

Comment: and the * refers to what ?

Comment: all your id that you have, like id of `listView`, `TextView` or anything else

Answer (score 0):

**Check this out :**
(Use Of Tag)

**Java Code:**

```
public class DynamicTetView extends Activity 
{
    RelativeLayout rl1;
    Button b1;
    TextView txt,txt3;
    int i = 0;
    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dynamic_tet_view);

        rl1 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rl1);
        b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param2 = new RelativeLayout.
                LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        param2.setMargins(5, 0, 0, 5);
        txt3 = new TextView(this);
        txt3.setId(500);
        Log.d("Id of txt3........", ""+txt3.getId());
         txt3.setText("Hii");
         rl1.addView(txt3, param2);

        for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param = new RelativeLayout.
                    LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            param.setMargins(5, 0, 0, 5);
            txt = new TextView(this);
            txt.setId(i+1);
```

> ```
>                   txt.setTag(i+1);
> ```

```
            Log.d("Id........", ""+txt.getId());

            map.put("hi"+txt.getId(), i);

            if(txt.getId()!=1)
            {
                param.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,(txt.getId()-1));
            }
            else
            {
                param.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,txt3.getId());
            }
            txt.setText("Text"+(i+1));
            rl1.addView(txt,param);

            txt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    String tag = v.getTag().toString();                 

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"You clicked "+tag, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }

        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                rl1.removeAllViews();
            }
        });

    }


}
```

**XML:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DynamicTetView" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
            android:text="Clear" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Just put above Java File & XML in your Project then you will get idea of how Tag works.

Comment: that's about `setTag(object)` and i'm asking about `setTag(key, Object)`